# Allowable current in Ni-Cr 80 20 gauge wire?

Tags: control-system, wiring

I am creating a small oven for curing composites out-of-autoclave, and have some Ni-Cr 80 20gauge wire lying around.  I need to put up to 8.6 amps through the wire at maximum.  The current is controlled with a PID bang-bang controller, so the duty cycle is not 100% at that current.

I know that 20 gauge Cu wire is rated for ~7 amps, but since Ni-Cr has a higher melting point I figured I might be able to get away with using my left over wire.  The one problem that might knock down the amount of amperage allowed even further is that the ambient environment of the furnace will be at 200 C at maximum steady state conditions, but the duty cycle on the wire will be much lower than on ramps up to steady temperature.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: without insulation to melt or burn? the melting point of the wire itself

Comment: why do you need 8.6A

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I need 1000 watts max power output, and that's how much current I would need to achieve that power level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can elevate the wire to Operating Temperature: 900°C

I believe this is a visible red temperature of heat energy levels.  **The closer the temperature is to melting temp, the more fragile it becomes.**

---

Melting temp:  Ni-Cr 1400'C  ,  Cu 1100'C

For straight wire at room temp:

```
No. / AWG)  204 °C  316 °C  427 °C  538 °C  649 °C  760 °C  871 °C  982 °C  1093 °C
      20    3.58    4.77    5.92    7.25    8.86    10.69   12.72   15.43   16.87
```

The ambient temp of 200'C means you subtract 175'C then with a coil wire the heat rise per amp may be another 50'C. More insulation could increase this even more.

The bottom line is the wire temperature margin below melting.

**Thus 650'C +250'C looks to be very close to the 900'C ideal working temp but geometric thermal resistance will affect your results.**

Answer (score 0):

The resistivity of NiCr is about 100x higher than that of Cu so you can pass about 1/10 the current for the same heating (all other things equal). Pretty much irrelevant since the Nichrome wire will likely run **much** hotter, by design.

If you have the bare element coiled and sitting in a groove in a firebrick you can allow it to get to red heat (~700°C) easily.

It's not straightforward to calculate the heat loss but if you have an idea of the total watts you will need for your oven, [this](http://www.alloywire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Element-Design.xls) spreadsheet will allow you get an idea of the watt density of the heater and the construction required to maintain a reasonable lifetime.